# Time access of elements in huge numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, large-data

I want to access and do some basic stuff with columns of a huge numpy array, non sparse, full of float, with shape 2 million x 800. 
So basically:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(2000000) # 2 millions elts

%timeit np.log10(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop
```

but if I create a bigger array with 800 columns, the access time to a column is ridiculously high:

```
a = np.ones((2000000, 800))  # take 12 Go RAM
b = a[:, 0].copy()  # 6 mins

%timeit np.log10(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.4 ms per loop
```

so my question is : how do you handle this situation ? Is there better objects to store such a big matrix and do simple operations like log10, plots, etc ? Or do I need to trick it, like creating 800 np.arrays with shape (2000000,) ? I've quickly read threads about Pytables and hdf, but I don't know if those solutions are appropriate for my problem, which looks very simple at first sight...

thanks a lot !

edit : I am on a xp 64 bits, and dtype of the array is float64.
I have tested this column access time with several shapes, and smth strange came up :

```
a = np.ones((1000000, 800), dtype="float64")
%timeit np.log10(a[:, 0])
1 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop
```

and

```
a = np.ones((1100000, 800), dtype="float64")  # just a few more column
b = np.log10(a[:, 0])  # 6 min 20 sec
```

there is a threshold for the time access around 1050000 lines, so I suspect that the problem is related to the maximum size in bits for a memory allocation on a 64 bits machine ?

Comment: How much physical RAM does your computer actually have?

Comment: It has 8 Go of RAM, but I'm using a SSD for the swap, so I can allocate easily 100 Go of RAM without slowing down the PC

Comment: Um... you think SSD is as fast as RAM? Really?

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned in the edit I've just added to the post, with just a bit less lines, it works fine. With 1 million lines, my computer has right now 20 Go of RAM allocated for the rest of my code

Comment: @RomainL: An SSD has access latencies that are several orders of magnitude slower than RAM, and similarly, several orders of magnitude lower bandwidth. Just because an SSD has lower latencies than a HDD doesn't mean it's anywhere close to the speed of RAM.

Comment: Those other 20 GB are probably inactive and thus irrelevant.

Comment: @RomainL: The maximum size in bits for memory allocation on a 64 bit machine starts at 16 TB and goes up from there (it varies depending on CPU and OS, but 16 TB is the absolute minimum I've heard of). 20 GB of allocated memory is meaningless. You'd likely have to map the entire contents of your hard disk into memory to even reach a measurable fraction of the limit.

Comment: So you are both suspecting a RAM issue ? Right now, with a 1 million line array (~ 8 Go in RAM), I've just made a copy of it (so now 16 Go in RAM), and I've made this np.log10 operations again, within a few seconds. But in the general case (with enough RAM), would you recommand using numpy array for such big amount of data ?